# Windows 10 Change Accent Color Start menu and application background

Tags: windows-10

I need assistance in changing the accent color on the start menu and application tile background in windows 10. For Example Adobe Reader DC application in the start menu, I want to change from blue background to storm (dark grey color).
From this 
[image] to this 
[image: Adobe DC Win10 default storm (dark grey color]

Is it possible to change using the registry or using PowerShell?

Comment: Do you need to use the registry or PowerShell? You can change the accent color from the settings.

Comment: @oldwooki Yes, I do need registry or PowerShell. I'm trying to step away from manually setting the accent color. I'm trying to automatically set the accent color using PowerShell or the registry.

Comment: Does [this](https://www.thelazyadministrator.com/2019/08/08/configure-windows-10-accent-color-with-intune-and-powershell/) answer your question?

Comment: @oldwooki This is definitely what I'm trying to do. Thanks, man. I'll let you know when it works.

Comment: @oldwooki I test the script from the link you posted it works!!! Thanks man